# Display data from sqlite database in jade template

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite, jade4j

I am trying to show all the data from a sqlite database into jade file. However i am manage to show list of all tables from the database into the template but when i want to display the data from the tables into a template i could not.It just shows blank page.

I also want to add pagination and search filter as the data is very large.

**The code of table_view.js:**

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db;

exports.get = function(req, res){
console.log("Serving " + \__filename);

    var db_name = req.params.db_resource;
var table = req.params.table;

var dbpath = 'databases/' + db_name;
db = new sqlite3.Database(dbpath, function(err){
    if (err) res.render('database/db_edit', {message: 'Error: ' + err});    
});

db.all(" select * from " + table, function(err, rows) {
    
    var message = rows.length > 0 ? "Viewing " + db_name + '/' + table : "No data found in table '" + table + "' in " + db_name;
    
    res.render('database/table_view', {message: message, rows: rows});
    db.close();
});

};
```

**The code of jade file:**

```
extends ../layout

block content
h1= message

    h3 Data
table
  - for (var r in rows)
      tr
        td= rows[r].id
        td= rows[r].some_text

br
```